# Formulario php, phpmailer, array

Tags: php, array, phpmailer

Llevo tiempo haciendo un formulario y estoy tratando de agregar un campo donde se puedan seleccionar varias opciones, ya intente de muchas formas y lo único que conseguí hasta el momento es que colocando **[ ]** en el input puedo conseguir captar todas opciones que se selecciones, pero al momento de enviar el formulario solo recibo array en donde deberían estar los valores que se enviaron, y no logro hacer que se impriman todos los valores.
De estos inputs tengo 8

```
   <label><input type="checkbox" name="unidad[]" value="Sedán 4
```

Esta es la sección de mi archivo php que recolecta la información

```
    $Nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $Correo = $_POST['correo'];
    $Telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
    $FechadeSalida = $_POST['inicio'];
    $FechadeRegreso = $_POST['regreso'];
    $RecorridoaRealizar = $_POST['recorrido'];
    $Unidad = $_POST["unidad"];
    $Detalles = $_POST['detalles'];
```

No se si al estar usando PHPmailer tenga que ver con esto esta seria la parte donde se genera el imprime la información que se va a enviar

```
 $mail->WordWrap = 50;
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject  =  "Sitio MarcoPolo";
    $mail->Body     =  "Nombre: $Nombre \n<br />".
    "Email: $Correo \n<br />".
    "Tel: $Telefono \n<br />".
    "Fecha de Salida: $FechadeSalida \n<br />".
    "Fecha de Regreso: $FechadeRegreso \n<br />".
    "Recorrido a Realizar: $RecorridoaRealizar \n<br />".
    "Unidad Requerida: $Unidad \n<br />".
    "Detalles: $Detalles \n<br />";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saludos te sugiero realizar de la siguiente manera teniendo el siguiente escenario(formulario):

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value 1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value 2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value 3">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value 4">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value 5">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

partiendo de este formulario en mi archivo php donde recibo "**test.php**" será:

```
  <?php
        if(isset($_POST['check_list'])){
          $unidades = join(",", $_POST['check_list']);
        }
        ...
        ..
         "Unidad Requerida: $unidades \n<br />".
        ...
        ..

    ?>
```

Explicación:

Lo que hago primero es verificar que efectivamente reciba valores del checkbox en cuestión eso lo hago con **isset**, acto seguido uso [join](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.join.php) que permite unir los elementos de un array en este caso une mediante la **coma**.

Es decir teniendo este array de ejemplo:

```
$unidad = ['Sedan 4', 'Mercedes 3', 'Chevrolet 2', 'Nissan 1'];
```

al aplicar el **join**

```
$unidades = join(",", $unidad);
```

obtengo:

```
Sedan 4,Mercedes 3,Chevrolet 2,Nissan 1
```

que seria la manera correcta de mostrar los valores del listado de checkbox.

Espero te sirva y suerte..!!

Comment: Me funciono perfecto, muchas gracias ahora ya todo esta funcionando como debería